# php captcha cannot load when upload to server

Tags: php

Regarding captcha In local PC is working fine but when upload to server (CentOS5.5)

PHP captcha cannot load.

This is php code call get_captcha.php:

```
$('#captcha-refresh').click(function() {  
  change_captcha();
});

function change_captcha()
{           
  document.getElementById('captcha').src="get_captcha.php?rnd=" + Math.random();
}
```

get_captcha.php:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
{
    $word_1 .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
{
    $word_2 .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}

$_SESSION['random_number'] = $word_1.' '.$word_2;
$dir = 'fonts/';
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);
$font = "recaptchaFont.ttf"; // font style
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);// color
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0,0, 709, 99, $white);
imagettftext ($image, 22, 0, 5, 30, $color, $dir.$font, $_SESSION['random_number']);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);  
$_SESSION['random_numberafter'] = $_SESSION['random_number'];
```

Comment: do you have any php errors on your server? what do you get as response?

Comment: NO. but it doesn't display captchar images in server but local is OK.why?

Comment: is the local and the server use the same configuration?

Comment: local use window 7 and sever user CentOS5.5 in VMware.

Comment: I am not familiar with Windows but for CentOS I would recommend to use error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors', 1); and try again (maybe also comment the headers) and see what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the GD library is installed in your server or not. You can check it by using phpinfo();

Try running the file get_captcha.php with a random number and see the images is displayed or not. Thanks

Comment: yes GD not installed yet in Centos 5.5 how to install ? i try yum install php-gd but not found.

Comment: This link might help. Go through all the comments. Thanks http://mattiasgeniar.be/2008/09/17/install-gd-library-for-php5-on-centos/